# How to add Attribute to tag in XML response using PHP and NuSOAP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to add a varying value as attribute in a XML formatted response. I already managed to create a WSDL, parse request and create a XML response using NuSoap. The problem I am facing now is that according to docs an attribute must be inserted at some point inside a tag like this:

```
<ns1:Expression code="Accepted/Rejected"/>
```

This response/value/attribute depends on whether the data from request is successfully stored in DB or not. So far I managed to create tags by adding complex types as arrays.

Inner tag:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Sender', 
    'complexType', 
    'struct', 
    'Sender', 
    '',
    array(
        'ID' => array('name' => 'ID', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'Code' => array('name' => 'Code', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'Sender' => array('name' => 'Sender', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
    )
);
```

Outer tag:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Response', 
    'complexType', 
    'array', 
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array', 
    array(),
    array(
    // 'Expression' must be a self closing tag,  with no value, just 1 attribute
        'Expression' => array('name' => 'Expression', '_' => 'code'),
        'Status' => array('name' => 'Status', 'type' => 'tns:Status')
    )
);
```

I have searched to no avail in docs since i need this to be sent as response.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't found a solution to this specific case. So a manually-generated response was created in the server.php file like this:

Function registration in server:

```
$server->register("Process",
array('input' => 'xsd:string'),
array('output' => 'tns:ResponseStruct'),
'ns:sales',
'ns:sales#ProcessMessageUpdate');
```

Return string with XML structure:

```
"<Respond>".
    "<ResponseCriteria>".
        "<ResponseExpression actionCode=\"".$actionCode."\"/>".
        "<ChangeStatus>".
            "<Code>".$code."</Code>".
            "<Message>".$message."</Message>".
        "</ChangeStatus>".
    "</ResponseCriteria>".
"</Respond>"
```

Hope this becomes useful for someone in the future